# ASP.NET Paypal page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, paypal

If I put on paypal 5$ , It will make it 5.00$ and so on with all amounts, what I want to do is replace that 00 with empty string and I can't seem to know how to do that exactly , my code is just not working and it gives me error when I try to access the page .

```
   <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false"     CodeFile="start_ipn.aspx.vb" Inherits="shop_start_ipn" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name="paypal">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="menordylan@yahoo.fr" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<%= Session.Item("currency_bought")%> Gems" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<%= Session.Item("currency_bought").Replace("00","")%>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.teamhyperion.co/shop/grunt.aspx" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.teamhyperion.co/uc/account_control.aspx" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        document.forms['paypal'].submit()
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting the error on the line I used the replace function , error is on french and I'm not sure what it should give in english but here is the error :

[ASP.NET PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeZll.png)

Comment: What's that error in English?

Comment: You can ignore that error , now I'm having something else and the Session.Item("currency_bought") is just not working when I use it on a second page after getting redirected , why is that ? it becomes nulled